# Website Menu Bar Not Appearing on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer

I have put together a website - hosted here:  http://curleylab.psych.columbia.edu/

I have  used `modernizr.js` - http://curleylab.psych.columbia.edu/js/modernizr.js
css stylesheet is here - http://curleylab.psych.columbia.edu/css/css1.css

For the menu at the top (visible and working on desktops), I have actually used `<footer>` tags for each page.  That bit of HTML looks like this:

```
<footer role="contentinfo">
            <div>
                <nav id="menu">
                    <ul role="navigation" class="nav">
                        <li><a href="curleyindex.html" class="nav-home"><strong>Curley</strong>Lab </a></li>
                        <li><a href="research.html">Research</a></li>
                        <li><a href="personnel.html">Personnel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="pubs.html">Publications</a></li>
                        <li><a href="teaching.html">Teaching</a></li>
                        <li><a href="rpackages.html">R packages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="rstats.html">R instruction</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

The relevant bits of css that apply to `<footer>` appear here:

```
/*Footer*/
footer[role=contentinfo] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    margin: 0 -1em;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}
footer[role=contentinfo] > div {
    max-width: 70em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
footer[role=contentinfo] p {
    margin: 0;

}
footer[role=contentinfo] .nav li a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 -1em;

}
footer[role=contentinfo] a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}
footer[role=contentinfo] a.nav-home {
    color: #fff;
}
footer[role=contentinfo] .f-rga {
    padding: 0.6em 0;
}
footer[role=contentinfo] img {
    max-width: 4.4em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -0.22em;
}
/*End Footer*/

/* Footer */


    footer[role=contentinfo] {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;

    }
    footer[role=contentinfo] .nav {
        float: left;
    }
    footer[role=contentinfo] .nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 0.8em;
    }
    footer[role=contentinfo] .nav li a {
        border: 0;
        font-size: 110%;
    }
    footer[role=contentinfo] .f-rga {
        float: right;
    }
```

The issue is that it seems to be working well enough on desktops, but on mobile devices the menu (everything contained in the footer) just doesn't appear.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem seems to be `position:fixed;`, if you remove it than the footer nav will appear... and add `height: auto;` than the background will be for the whole footer navigation black

Comment: Using this appears to give me a functional footer on mobile devices but it also pins the footer to the bottom of the screen on the desktop.  I would like to keep the header across the full width of the screen also (I know I've been using 'footer' for that which is poor). I tried doing this with header, but do not get full width (it truncates itself).

Comment: A hacky work-around solution seems to be adding two sets of footers per page with different classes - one for the top bar and the other for the bottom (this one then appears on mobiles also).  It doesn't look that great though - hopefully there is a better way